# Error when trying to set a struct variable to another

Tags: arrays, go, quicksort

I'm currently having trouble when trying to set a variable in one of my structs equivalent to another variable defined in the line above.  This might not make sense through that description, however my code below should describe what I'm trying to do.

```
type Quick struct{
    Slice   []int
}


// CreateQuicksortObj creates a quicksort object 
func CreateQuicksortObj(size int) (*Quick) {
    var q *Quick
    var unsortedSlice []int

    unsortedSlice = GenerateSlice(size) // this returns a []int of size: size
    q.Slice = unsortedSlice   // error occurs here

    q.shuffle()
    
    return q
}
```

The error is as follows:
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x10ab52e]

Answer (score 1):

You declared `q` as a pointer, but you dereference it without assigning it to a value. You can do one of the following:

Declare it as value, return address

```
var q Quick
...
return &q
```

Declare it as pointer, but initialize it:

```
var q = &Quick{}
...
return q
```

Comment: Awesome, I should have caught that!  Thank you!